# Yii unit-tests fixtures not accessible in tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii, phpunit

config/test.php

```
'components'=>array(
    'fixture'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.test.CDbFxtureManager'
    ),
),
```

tests/unit/EntityTest.php (extends CDbTestCase)

```
public $fixtures = array('entities'=>'Entity'),
```

tests/fixtures/Entity.php

```
return array(
    'entity1'=>array('slug'=>'slug1', 'title'=>'title1'),
    'entity2'=>array('slug'=>'slug2', 'title'=>'title2'),
);
```

Now, in EntityTest class I try to get my entities

```
$entities = $this->entities;
$entity = $this->entities('entity1');
```

Output is 'Unknown property "entities" for class "EntityTest"'. Testing class is 'Entity', table name in database is 'tbl_entity', 'tablePrefix' option of 'CDbConnection' component is set to 'tbl_'

Comment: Before accessing `$this->entities` put `var_dump($this);` to see what properties it does have. Also, what type of value are you expecting it to hold? It looks like you're trying to call it as a function on the following line rather than accessing it as a property. Perhaps just remove the line `$entities = $this->entities;`.

Comment: You have a misprint: "CDbFxtureManager" => "CDbFixtureManager"

Comment: Try its alternative syntax, `$entity = $this->entities['entity1'];`

Comment: Also try [this if you are using setUp() method][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20770725/3134155

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's go necroposting! :)

Your problem is the naming of the file in fixtures. You mention that it's a `tests/fixtures/Entity.php`, which should be after the name of your *Model*, class, but in fact, files in `fixtures` folder should be named after `tableName`s of your Models. I believe the real table name for your `Entity` model is `entity` (all in lower case), so just rename the file. I had the similar problem several times, and the solution is clearly stated in the documentation: ["A fixture is represented as a PHP script whose name (without suffix) is the same as the table name (if schema name is needed, it should be prefixed to the table name)."](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbFixtureManager)

Comment: Legend, did you know I would need this in 10 hours?

Comment: I still don't understand it. If I have a model called Entity, which relates to a table called entities, how should the line `$public $fixtures = array(
        'Entity' => 'entities'
    );` look like? In this particular case, when I use this line, I get the error `Class 'entities' not found`.

Comment: @physicalattraction Definition of fixtures is mapping of virtual attribute of the test case class to the name of the entities class. Hence in the OP's code example `$fixtures = ['entities' => 'Entity']`. With this setup, test case will have attribute `entities`, which will map to the predefined set of models of class `Entity`. Your code is wrong, because it maps `Entity` attribute name to the `entities`, which is not a name of any class in your system. And PHP tells you exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

Also try [this if you are using setUp() method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20770725/3134155). Just call parent::setUp(), when you are redefining it with your own method.

Comment: Thanks! This was my second problem after I'd fixed the filenames as per @hijarian 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$entity = $this->entities['entity1']; // returns an array
$entity = $this->entities('entity1'); // returns an active record
```

Comment: though not related to the question, my problem also included this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this solution [Yii Fixtures Issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886947/yii-fixtures-issue) I also came up with the same problem. I overlook the class to extend, make sure to extend the CDbTestCase.